# resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null returns null

Tags: java, android

It returns null for default sms and call apps while running from my android studio, but worked when executed with someone else's, From my android studio it is executing the else block and if I put startActivity(intent) without if statement it executes

```
callDial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(userData.get(position).getContNum()!= null)
            {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                String strMobileNo = String.format("tel:%s",
                        userData.get(position).getContNum());
                //String m = "tel: " + txtCALL.getText().toString();
               /* Log.d("STR MOBILE NO : " , strMobileNo);*/

                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(strMobileNo));
                //startActivity(callIntent);
                if(callIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null)
                    context.startActivity(callIntent);
                else
                    Log.v("ERROR : " , "Call Activity Cannot be started");
            }
        }
    });
```

While on my android studio this block of code is executing the if block i.e the direct call one without opening default app. . .

```
callDirect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!userData.get(position).getContNum().isEmpty()) {
                String mobileNo = String.format("tel: %s", userData.get(position).getContNum());
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(mobileNo));
                if (callIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    context.startActivity(callIntent);
                } else
                    Log.d("CALL ERROR ", "CALL CANNOT BE INITIATED");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You need to add an [mcve] . right now your question does not make much sense.

Comment: ok done editing please answer now

Comment: What's your target SDK level and API level where you're running the code on?

Comment: my minimum target level is Marshmallow and I am running on Android 11

Answer (score 0):

On Android 11 and later you need to declare a `queries` element in your manifest to have visibility to other packages with methods like `resolveActivity()`. See: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility

Comment: and what will  <data> attribute hold for opening default msg and call app?

Comment: still not working and the same code worked from someone else's android studio

Comment: it is working now, I had to clear cache of phone and optimize it.